# Electricity from electrons

Tags: electricity

If I was able to get electrons flowing through a glass tube what happens if I put wires connected to a bulb into that stream of electrons?

Comment: What sort of apparatus are you dealing with? I presume a cathode ray tube, but can you please clarify, @Emmanuel Seun.

Comment: How exactly are your electrons going to go through the tube?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is nothing will happen. You can not pass the electron in an ordinary glass tube as like the flow of water. If you want to pass the electrons in to a tube , that tube should be maintained with very low pressure nearly vacuum.Then only you can pass the electrons in to it. After that the flow of electrons only will not glow the bulb. it needs some voltage. If only you give the certain voltage, the bulb will glow. 
The relation shows

```
V = I*R
```

Here V is the voltage and I is the current and R is the resistance.This is from the Ohm's law. so the circuit needs necessary current and voltage to do some work.